# Bash: Reading lines from a specified file

Tags: bash, file

In Bash, I would like to know how to read lines from a file in a directory i specifiy so that there are no arguements along with running the script. All I have seen if suggestions for running a script with a file given as the arguement rather than one specified.

Comment: Please, what do you mean with "a file in a directory [I] specifiy so that there are no [arguments] along with running the script"? You specify a directory and the script choses a file, at random or based on some criteria? what else?

Comment: by ""a file in a directory [I] specifiy so that there are no [arguments] along with running the script" I mean that knowing beforehand that "example.txt" will be in /path/to I can read it line by line

Comment: My understanding: "I have different files, all named _example.txt_, sprinkled in different directories, and I want to process one of them, given that I know the path to that specific file".

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < filename
```

Comment: won't this read every file in the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
% cat read_line_by_line_example.txt_inside
dir="$1"
[ -f "$dir"/example.txt ] || exit 1
# borrowing from Cyrus
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  # do watever you want with "$line"
done < "$dir"/example.txt
% sh read_line_by_line_example.txt_inside "a/b/c/d/my dir"
line 1
line b
last line
%
```